# Get MSSQL RaiseError Message from VB.NET code

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures

**Stored Procedure**

```sql
ALTER procedure [work].[update_status]
    @item_id int,
    @next_status varchar(60)
as begin

declare
    @status varchar(60),
    @last_status_date datetime2;

set @status = (select [status] from work.items where id = @item_id); --set status to current status

--Check validity of status change
if not exists (select * from work.status_precedence where status = @status and next_status = @next_status) 
begin
    declare @err varchar(255) = 'Changes not applied: ' + @next_status + ' is not a valid state following ' + @status + '.  See work.status_precedence for valid status advancements.';
    raiserror(@err,0,-1);
    return -1;
end

--Get date time of last status update
set @last_status_date = isnull(
    (   select max(added) 
        from work.status_changes 
        where item_id = @item_id
    ),
    (   select requested
        from work.items
        where id = @item_id
    ));

--If request has not been reviewed.
if @status = 'Pending Review' and not exists (select * from work.request_reviews where item_id = @item_id and approval = 1 and reviewed > @last_status_date)
begin
    raiserror(N'Changes not applied: Request has not been reviewed since set to pending status.',0,-1);
    return -1;
end

--If developer has not been assigned.
if @status = 'Request Reviewed' and not exists (select * from work.assignments where item_id = @item_id and assigned > @last_status_date)
begin
    raiserror(N'Changes not applied: Developer has not been assigned.',0,-1);
    return -1;
end

--If level of effort is not assigned.
if @status = 'Assigned' and not exists (select * from work.developer_review where item_id = @item_id and added > @last_status_date)
begin
    raiserror(N'Changes not applied: Level of effort has not been assigned.',0,-1);
    return -1;
end

--If work hasn't been peer reviewed.
if @status = 'Peer Review' and @next_status = 'Business Review' and not exists (select * from work.peer_reviews where item_id = @item_id and approval = 1 and reviewed > @last_status_date)
begin
    raiserror(N'Changes not applied: No approved peer review after work item last set to Peer Review status.',0,-1);
    return -1;
end

--If work hasn't completed business review.
if @status = 'Business Review' and @next_status = 'Complete' and not exists (select * from work.business_reviews where item_id = @item_id and approval = 1 and reviewed > @last_status_date)
begin
    raiserror(N'Changes not applied: No approved business review after work item last set to Business Review status.',0,-1);
    return -1;
end

--Log status.
insert into work.status_changes (
    item_id,
    previous_status,
    new_status
) values (
    @item_id,
    @status,
    @next_status
);

--Set current status.
update work.items set status = @next_status
where id = @item_id;

return 0;
end;
```

**VB.NET Code Behind**

```vb
try
    command.connection= connection
    command.commandtype = storedprocedure
    command.commandtext = "work.update_status"
    command.parameters.addwithvalue("item_id",value)
    connection.open()
    command.executenonquery()
catch ex as exception
    msgbox(ex.message)
end try
```

I want to get the raise error message from the code behind but it does not throw an exception and never hits the catch block. I found suggestion online to change the error severity of raiseerror but I do not own the stored procedure so I am not able to change it. Thanks!

Comment: I added the entire stored procedure. I cannot edit it because it is used by other people. just wanting to know if there is a way i can get the raisederror from VB.NET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To capture messages with a severity of 10 and less, add a handler for the  `InfoMessage`(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.infomessage(v=vs.110).aspx) event to the connection. C# example:

```
connection.InfoMessage += connection_InfoMessage;
static void connection_InfoMessage(object sender, SqlInfoMessageEventArgs e)
{
    MessageeBox.Show(e.Message);
}
```